# Best practice for constant value in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a where clause that compares two columns to the following string. Does this concatenation run for every row? Should this string (and concatenation) be left in twice or should I create a variable to hold the result and use that in the WHERE clause?

`CONCAT('%', @myVar, 'dr')`

Comment: SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: if it's SQL server, may try: `DECLARE @var char(200);  
SET @var = CONCAT('%', @myVar, 'dr');  `, and use @var in the where clause

Comment: The `LIKE` is going to be more expensive than the concatenation.

Comment: The DBMS should be wise enough to concatenate constants just once. If it doesn't, it'll cost you some nanoseconds extra, so why bother?

Comment: Sorry, It is SQL Server. I was kind of assuming it would be optimized away but I am not really sure. Speed is a BIG issue right now so I am trying to do every little bit I can to help things along.

Comment: Glad to see that you are trying to save every bit where performance matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the Execution Plan for your expression in a test table present in my database. The table has two `nvarchar(50)` columns namely `firstname` and `fullname` .

[image]

I can clearly see that even for three `AND` conditions in where clause that I put deliberately, the SQL Server engine is showing 0% cost for both the `compute scalar` steps. It is clearly evident of the fact that irrespective of whether you create a separate variable for the concatenation expression or leave it in-line in your where clause it is not going to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to hold the result and use that in the WHERE clause